# Magento - Add custom attribute to navigation

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have the below code that creates a custom menu in Magento:

```
<?php
/**
 * Catalog navigation
 */

class Infortis_Ultimo_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    //NEW:
    protected $_isAccordion = FALSE;

    protected $_categoryInstance = null;

    /**
     * Current category key
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_currentCategoryKey;

    /**
     * Array of level position counters
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_itemLevelPositions = array();

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->addData(array(
            'cache_lifetime'    => false,
            'cache_tags'        => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::CACHE_TAG, Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group::CACHE_TAG),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Get Key pieces for caching block content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        $shortCacheId = array(
            'CATALOG_NAVIGATION',
            Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
            Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName(),
            Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template'),
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(),
            'template' => $this->getTemplate(),
            'name' => $this->getNameInLayout(),
            $this->getCurrenCategoryKey()
        );
        $cacheId = $shortCacheId;

        $shortCacheId = array_values($shortCacheId);
        $shortCacheId = implode('|', $shortCacheId);
        $shortCacheId = md5($shortCacheId);

        $cacheId['category_path'] = $this->getCurrenCategoryKey();
        $cacheId['short_cache_id'] = $shortCacheId;

        return $cacheId;
    }

    /**
     * Get current category key
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCurrenCategoryKey()
    {
        if (!$this->_currentCategoryKey) {
            $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
            if ($category) {
                $this->_currentCategoryKey = $category->getPath();
            } else {
                $this->_currentCategoryKey = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
            }
        }

        return $this->_currentCategoryKey;
    }

    /**
     * Get catagories of current store
     *
     * @return Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection
     */
    public function getStoreCategories()
    {
        $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
        return $helper->getStoreCategories();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve child categories of current category
     *
     * @return Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection
     */
    public function getCurrentChildCategories()
    {
        $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
        $category   = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
        /* @var $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
        $categories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
        $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $layer->prepareProductCollection($productCollection);
        $productCollection->addCountToCategories($categories);
        return $categories;
    }

    /**
     * Checkin activity of category
     *
     * @param   Varien_Object $category
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function isCategoryActive($category)
    {
        if ($this->getCurrentCategory()) {
            return in_array($category->getId(), $this->getCurrentCategory()->getPathIds());
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function _getCategoryInstance()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_categoryInstance)) {
            $this->_categoryInstance = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        }
        return $this->_categoryInstance;
    }

    /**
     * Get url for category data
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCategoryUrl($category)
    {
        if ($category instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category) {
            $url = $category->getUrl();
        } else {
            $url = $this->_getCategoryInstance()
                ->setData($category->getData())
                ->getUrl();
        }

        return $url;
    }

    /**
     * Return item position representation in menu tree
     *
     * @param int $level
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getItemPosition($level)
    {
        if ($level == 0) {
            $zeroLevelPosition = isset($this->_itemLevelPositions[$level]) ? $this->_itemLevelPositions[$level] + 1 : 1;
            $this->_itemLevelPositions = array();
            $this->_itemLevelPositions[$level] = $zeroLevelPosition;
        } elseif (isset($this->_itemLevelPositions[$level])) {
            $this->_itemLevelPositions[$level]++;
        } else {
            $this->_itemLevelPositions[$level] = 1;
        }

        $position = array();
        for($i = 0; $i <= $level; $i++) {
            if (isset($this->_itemLevelPositions[$i])) {
                $position[] = $this->_itemLevelPositions[$i];
            }
        }
        return implode('-', $position);
    }

    /**
     * Render category to html
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category
     * @param int Nesting level number
     * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is last, affects list item class
     * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is first, affects list item class
     * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is outermost, affects list item class
     * @param string Extra class of outermost list items
     * @param string If specified wraps children list in div with this class
     * @param boolean Whether ot not to add on* attributes to list item
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml($category, $level = 0, $isLast = false, $isFirst = false,
        $isOutermost = false, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $noEventAttributes = false)
    {
        if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
            return '';
        }
        $html = array();

        // get all children
        if (Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat')->isEnabled()) {
            $children = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
            $childrenCount = count($children);
        } else {
            $children = $category->getChildren();
            $childrenCount = $children->count();
        }
        $hasChildren = ($children && $childrenCount);

        // select active children
        $activeChildren = array();
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            if ($child->getIsActive()) {
                $activeChildren[] = $child;
            }
        }
        $activeChildrenCount = count($activeChildren);
        $hasActiveChildren = ($activeChildrenCount > 0);

        // prepare list item html classes
        $classes = array();
        $classes[] = 'level' . $level;
        $classes[] = 'nav-' . $this->_getItemPosition($level);
        if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
        }
        $linkClass = '';
        if ($isOutermost && $outermostItemClass) {
            $classes[] = $outermostItemClass;
            $linkClass = ' class="'.$outermostItemClass.'"';
        }
        if ($isFirst) {
            $classes[] = 'first';
        }
        if ($isLast) {
            $classes[] = 'last';
        }
        if ($hasActiveChildren) {
            $classes[] = 'parent';
        }

        //NEW: add special class if level == 1 and menu is not an accordion.
        if ($this->_isAccordion == FALSE && $level == 1) {
            $classes[] = 'item';
        }

        // prepare list item attributes
        $attributes = array();
        if (count($classes) > 0) {
            $attributes['class'] = implode(' ', $classes);
        }
        if ($hasActiveChildren && !$noEventAttributes) {
             $attributes['onmouseover'] = 'toggleMenu(this,1)';
             $attributes['onmouseout'] = 'toggleMenu(this,0)';
        }

        // assemble list item with attributes
        $htmlLi = '<li';
        foreach ($attributes as $attrName => $attrValue) {
            $htmlLi .= ' ' . $attrName . '="' . str_replace('"', '\"', $attrValue) . '"';
        }
        $htmlLi .= '>';
        $html[] = $htmlLi;

if ($level == 0 && $hasChildren) {
        $html[] = '<a href="javascript:void(0)"'.$linkClass.'>';
        $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
        $html[] = '</a>';
}
else {
        $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
        $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
        $html[] = '</a>';
} 

        // render children
        $htmlChildren = '';
        $j = 0;
        foreach ($activeChildren as $child) {
            $htmlChildren .= $this->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(
                $child,
                ($level + 1),
                ($j == $activeChildrenCount - 1),
                ($j == 0),
                false,
                $outermostItemClass,
                $childrenWrapClass,
                $noEventAttributes
            );
            $j++;
        }
        if (!empty($htmlChildren)) {

            //NEW: add opener if menu is used as accordion.
            if ($this->_isAccordion == TRUE)
                $html[] = '<span class="opener">&nbsp;</span>';

            if ($childrenWrapClass) {
                $html[] = '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
            }
            $html[] = '<ul class="level' . $level . '">';
            $html[] = $htmlChildren;
            $html[] = '</ul>';
            if ($childrenWrapClass) {
                $html[] = '</div>';
            }
        }

        $html[] = '</li>';

        $html = implode("\n", $html);
        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * Render category to html
     *
     * @deprecated deprecated after 1.4
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category
     * @param int Nesting level number
     * @param boolean Whether ot not this item is last, affects list item class
     * @return string
     */
    public function drawItem($category, $level = 0, $last = false)
    {
        return $this->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml($category, $level, $last);
    }

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
     */
    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')) {
            return Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCurrentCategoryPath()
    {
        if ($this->getCurrentCategory()) {
            return explode(',', $this->getCurrentCategory()->getPathInStore());
        }
        return array();
    }

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category
     * @return string
     */
    public function drawOpenCategoryItem($category) {
        $html = '';
        if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
            return $html;
        }

        $html.= '<li';

        if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) {
            $html.= ' class="active"';
        }

        $html.= '>'."\n";
        $html.= '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"><span>'.$this->htmlEscape($category->getName()).'</span></a>'."\n";

        if (in_array($category->getId(), $this->getCurrentCategoryPath())){
            $children = $category->getChildren();
            $hasChildren = $children && $children->count();

            if ($hasChildren) {
                $htmlChildren = '';
                foreach ($children as $child) {
                    $htmlChildren.= $this->drawOpenCategoryItem($child);
                }

                if (!empty($htmlChildren)) {
                    $html.= '<ul>'."\n"
                            .$htmlChildren
                            .'</ul>';
                }
            }
        }
        $html.= '</li>'."\n";
        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * Render categories menu in HTML
     *
     * @param bool Add opener if menu is used as accordion.
     * @param int Level number for list item class to start from
     * @param string Extra class of outermost list items
     * @param string If specified wraps children list in div with this class
     * @return string
     */
    public function renderCategoriesMenuHtml($isAccordion = FALSE, $level = 0, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '')
    {
        //NEW: save additional attribute
        $this->_isAccordion = $isAccordion;

        $activeCategories = array();
        foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $child) {
            if ($child->getIsActive()) {
                $activeCategories[] = $child;
            }
        }
        $activeCategoriesCount = count($activeCategories);
        $hasActiveCategoriesCount = ($activeCategoriesCount > 0);

        if (!$hasActiveCategoriesCount) {
            return '';
        }

        $html = '';
        $j = 0;
        foreach ($activeCategories as $category) {
            $html .= $this->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(
                $category,
                $level,
                ($j == $activeCategoriesCount - 1),
                ($j == 0),
                true,
                $outermostItemClass,
                $childrenWrapClass,
                true
            );
            $j++;
        }

        return $html;
    }

}
```

I would like to add a custom category attribute (menu_label) to the menu items.  I have created the custom category attribute using this tutorial http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/

The attribute shows up fine in admin and I can get it to print out on my normal template files but can't get it to show in this menu.

I thought $this->escapeHtml($category->getMenuLabel()) would have done it but this doesn't output anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You have to consider the fact that Magento is not acting the same with flat categories enable or disable.
I suppose you may be with flat category enabled, in your case, because it should work otherwise.

(Please check in *System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Frontend* the field *Use Flat Catalog Category*. If it is set to *Yes*, then that is where your problem is.)

To solve it add this to your *config.xml* in the `frontend` node:

```xml
<events>
    <catalog_category_flat_loadnodes_before>
        <observers>
            <somemodule>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>somemodule/observer</class>
                <method>addMenuAttributes</method>
            </somemodule>
        </observers>
    </catalog_category_flat_loadnodes_before>
</events>
```

Then create an *Observer.php* in the Model folder of your module (the model folder should be declared in your *config.xml* too, of course).

Here is the observer code:

```php
<?php
class Somecompany_Somemodule_Model_Observer {

    public function addMenuAttributes(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $observer->getSelect()->columns(
            array('menu_label')
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You assumtion is incorrect:

```
$this->escapeHtml($category->getMenuLabel())
```

This assumes $category is indeed a Category Model (Mage_Catalog_Model_category) when infact it's not, it's a Node object.

if you look here:

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer::_addCategoriesToMenu()
```

You will notice where the actual catalog model is used to create an array which is passed to the Navigation routine as a Varien_Data_Tree_Node.
You can add in your custom attribute here, and then access it inside the block.

```
$categoryData = array(
    'name' => $category->getName(),
    'id' => $nodeId,
    'url' => Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
    'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category),
    'my_attribute' => $category->getData('my_attribute')
);
```

You will then be able to access the attribute inside your custom menu block:

```
$child->getData('my_attribute');
//$this->escapeHtml($category->getData('my_attribute'))
```

Comment: Tried that but got this error PHP Fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in Navigation.php on line 272. May be something really simple.  I am a total novice :)